KeepasDX: Is the password sent anywhere?
Does the database password ever get sent to the Google servers if I use KeepasDX app to open and decrypt a file stored on Google Drive storage via SAF?
If I am opening a .kdbx database file through generic android file picker (documentsui, invoked by the app upon clicking "Use existing database" button) using Google Drive's SAF (Storage access framework to do so) will the password/has/key be shown to the server when I decrypt it inside the app or is the decryption done locally?


For questions about apps please always include a link to the app sources to make sure users understand about which app your question is about as apps can have different names in different countries. Please do not use external services to host mages. Stackexchange has a built-in image hosting service you can use.

So the answer is: no, it isnt getting sent to the filesystem  (at least according to this guy from the official github of KeepasDX). And nor does the file get decrypted anywhere except RAM.
So incasha were wondering if its safe to store your .kdbx file on a cloud storage that you do not trust not to peek then: yes, as long as the password is strong and the app is reliable (at least this app is

In my opinion you can bypass the question if someone else can open a kdbx file e.g. from a cloud storage. You simply need to create a static random file of a few KB and use password+key file. The key file is never stored in the cloud as it does not change. Copy the key file manually via USB on each device where you want to open the kdbx. Now it doesn't matter how secure the password is, without the key file it is impossible to read the kdbx.

Inconvenient. symbol count

Sorry I don't understand your comment.

I am saying that this way of doing things is inconvenient and adding the text "symbol count" because it requires the comment to be longer
